# How do I add an apt repository in prudentia

Tags: prudentia

I'm trying to use prudentia to install postgresql. On the latest version of the develop branch, there is a task for posgresql, but that installs the wrong version for me.

I have found [here](http://technobytz.com/install-postgresql-9-3-ubuntu.html) that I need a special apt repository to get the latest (9.3) version. But I need some help installing it from prudentia.

I did see [some example](https://github.com/StarterSquad/prudentia/blob/master/tasks/tor.yml) in code, but I couldn't find anything about adding repositories in the docs. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an apt repository there are two ways.

1) The simplest one is to use the Ansible [apt_repository module](http://docs.ansible.com/apt_repository_module.html) that requires the python-apt package installed on the target machine. This module accepts both deb and ppa repositories style.
A Prudentia task for installing PostgreSQL has been provided using this method and can be found [here](https://github.com/StarterSquad/prudentia/blob/master/prudentia/tasks/postgresql.yml).

2) The second is to provide an apt source file. This approach doesn't have any dependency. The Prudentia [Chrome bundled task](https://github.com/StarterSquad/prudentia/blob/master/prudentia/tasks/chrome.yml) uses this approach.